# How do I return a list of merged tuples?

Tags: haskell

Currently I have a list of tuples [ (1 , [1]) , (2 , [1]) , (3 , [1]) , (1 , [2]) , (3 , [2]) , (1 , [3]) ]. I'd like to return a list of [ (1 , [1,2,3]) , (2 , [1]) , (3 , [1,2]) ].

I have written a merge method that merges two tuples.

```
merge :: Ord a => (a,[Int]) -> (a,[Int]) -> (a,[Int])
merge (x,y) (w,z) = (x, y ++ z )
```

And a method that checks if the first element of each tuple is equal.

```
isEqual :: Ord a => (a,[Int]) -> (a,[Int]) -> Bool
isEqual (x,y) (w,z)
  | x == w = True
  | otherwise = False
```

I'm having trouble coming up with a way to run the isEqual and merge methods on each element though to get to the answer. Would you guys recommend a fold or a recursive method? Thanks!

Comment: The easy (and efficient) way is to go through `Data.Map.fromListWith`

Comment: Alternatively, have a look at [groupBy](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/groupBy-0.1.0.0/docs/Data-List-GroupBy.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Haskell: converting a list of (a, b) key-value pairs (with possibly repeated keys) to a list of (a, \[b\]) grouped by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15514486/haskell-converting-a-list-of-a-b-key-value-pairs-with-possibly-repeated-key)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, to solve this type of problem *efficiently*, you need to store the values in a map structure that can be easily accessed by the "key" on which you're matching.  That way, when you run across `(1, [2])`, you can quickly consult the map, see that you already have `(1, [1])`, and combine them to get `(1, [1,2])`.  Later, when you run across `(1, [3])`, you can quickly find `(1, [1,2])` in the map and combine them to get `(1, [1,2,3])`, and so on...

For this specific problem, there's a short solution using facilities in `Data.Map`:

```
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as Map

gather :: (Ord a) => [(a, [Int])] -> [(a, [Int])]
gather = Map.toList . Map.fromListWith (++) . reverse
```

after which:

```
> gather [(1 , [1]) , (2 , [1]) , (3 , [1]) , (1 , [2]) , (3 , [2]) , (1 , [3])]
[(1,[1,2,3]),(2,[1]),(3,[1,2])]
```

Here, `Map.fromListWith` runs through a list of key-value pairs `[(k,v)]` and adds them, one by one, to a new map.  As each pair is added, if the key isn't already in the map, the value (in your case, a singleton value like `[1]` or `[2]`) is added under that key.  If the key *is* already in the map, the new value is combined with the old value using the supplied function `(++)` (i.e., as `new_singleton_value ++ existing_list_of_values`).  This has the effect of creating a list of values in reverse order from the input list, so that's why I pre-processed the input list with `reverse`.  (If the order doesn't matter, you should drop it.)

A more common variant of this problem is writing a function that takes a list of pairs:

```
[(1,1), (2,1), (3,1), (1,2), (3,2), (1,3)]
```

where the values aren't already lists.  The solution is the same. You just pre-process the list with `map (\(k,v) -> (k,[v])`.  This solution is covered in the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15514486/haskell-converting-a-list-of-a-b-key-value-pairs-with-possibly-repeated-key) mentioned in the comments.